# How to concatenate strings in rows of dataframe usings ids?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-concatenation

Here is an example of my dataset.

```
d={'Report id': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'sentences': ['There is also a faint ground glass nodule. ', 'Other two ill  defined, small ground glass lesions are seen.', 'There is a small nodule at medial aspect of left breast, measured 11 mm in size.', 'Two heterogeneous enhancing lesions at lateral segment of left lobe']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to concatenate the rows of a data frame based on the report id which starts from 0. If the rows have the same report id, it should be concatenated into one row. Following is my expected output.

```
dd = {'Report id': [0, 1], 'sentences': ['There is also a faint ground glass nodule. ' 'Other two ill  defined, small ground glass lesions are seen.', 'There is a small nodule at medial aspect of left breast, measured 11 mm in size.' 'Two heterogeneous enhancing lesions at lateral segment of left lobe']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)
```

I was trying to join or concatenate like this. Please help!

```
res = pd.concat(df["sentences"], on=['Report id'])
```

Comment: `df1.groupby('Report id').sentences.agg(''.join)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `apply`

**Ex:**

```
d={'Report id': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'sentences': ['There is also a faint ground glass nodule. ', 'Other two ill  defined, small ground glass lesions are seen.', 'There is a small nodule at medial aspect of left breast, measured 11 mm in size.', 'Two heterogeneous enhancing lesions at lateral segment of left lobe']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df1.groupby('Report id')['sentences'].apply(" ".join))
```

**Output:**

```
Report id
0    There is also a faint ground glass nodule.  Ot...
1    There is a small nodule at medial aspect of le...
Name: sentences, dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you help me with this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242824/how-to-make-operations-on-python-dataframe-based-on-specific-values-of-another-c